# What to use for `Iterator::pointer` when nothing makes sense?

Tags: c++

For example, consider some hypothetical `to_upper_iterator` that iterates over a range of characters, returning `std::toupper` for `operator*`. These iterator aliases make sense to me:

```
template <typename CharT>
struct to_upper_iterator
{
    using value_type = CharT;
    using reference = CharT;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
};
```

What *doesn't* make sense is what should/could be used for the `pointer` alias. I tried leaving it off, but sure enough I got compilation errors. It seems as though this is due to an addition in C++17. Summarized by [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) for the `std::iterator_traits` type:

> If `Iterator` does not have the five member types `difference_type`, `value_type`, `pointer`, `reference`, and `iterator_category`, then this template has no members by any of those names (`std::iterator_traits` is SFINAE-friendly)

So the question is: for types like this, should I just define `pointer` to *something* - my leading favorite being `void` or `void*` - or would it make more sense to do something like specialize `std::iterator_traits<to_upper_iterator>` so that it doesn't contain an alias for `pointer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard c++ models of `OutputIterator` define all to be `void`.

example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator

I would be inclined to do the same for those type that have no meaning in the context of your iterator type.

This iterator of yours looks like it's modelling the concept of an adapter. In which case I might be inclined to start along these lines:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename BaseIter>
struct to_upper_iterator
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<BaseIter>::value_type;
    using reference = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::add_const_t<value_type>>;
    using pointer = std::add_pointer_t<std::add_const_t<value_type>>;
    using difference_type = typename std::iterator_traits<BaseIter>::difference_type;
    using iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<BaseIter>::iterator_category;

    to_upper_iterator(BaseIter iter = BaseIter()) : iter_(iter) {}

    value_type operator*() const { return std::toupper(*underlying()); }
    to_upper_iterator& operator++()
    {
        iter_++;
        return *this;
    }

    to_upper_iterator operator++(int)
    {
        auto copy = *this;
        iter_++;
        return copy;
    }

    bool operator!=(const to_upper_iterator& other) const {
        return iter_ != other.iter_;
    }

    // etc. use enable_if to enable functionality depending on iterator_category

private:
    BaseIter& underlying() { return iter_; }
    BaseIter const& underlying() const { return iter_; }

    BaseIter iter_;
};

template<class Iter>
auto make_upper_iterator(Iter iter)
{
    return to_upper_iterator<Iter>(iter);
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "abcdef";

    auto first = make_upper_iterator(a.begin());
    auto last = make_upper_iterator(a.end());

    std::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    const char b[] = "abcdef";
    std::copy(make_upper_iterator(std::begin(b)),
        make_upper_iterator(std::end(b) - 1),
        std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The question does not describe an output iterator. An output iterator is a pure sink. What the question describes is a transforming iterator adaptor.

Comment: @Johan right. I have chosen the extreme case to demonstrate the point. Perhaps a better model in this case would be `istream_iterator<>` which defines pointer as `const CharT*`

Answer (score 2):

`to_upper_iterator::pointer` should be a type that can point to the `value_type` and to mark that you can't modify the value you should make it const, i.e. `const CharT*`

Comment: What should it point to? (there's a sensible answer, but it changes the design of the iterator significantly)

Comment: @JonathanWakely It should, of course, be a type. Sloppy writing on my behalf.

Comment: That's not what I meant. If it's a pointer of type `const CharT*` what does it point to? i.e. what is its value? If it's null it's not very useful, and if it's not null it has to point to something.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own answer, but assuming SO doesn't force me, won't mark it as the answer. It seems as though the relevant phrasing is in § 27.4.1

> **27.4.1 Iterator traits [iterator.traits]**
>
> To implement algorithms only in terms of iterators, it is often necessary to determine the value and difference
>   types that correspond to a particular iterator type. Accordingly, it is required that if `Iterator` is the type of
>   an iterator, the types
>
> ```
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category
> ```
>
> be defined as the iterator’s difference type, value type and iterator category, respectively. In addition, the
>   types
>
> ```
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer
> ```
>
> shall be defined as the iterator’s reference and pointer types, that is, for an iterator object `a`, the same type
>   as the type of `*a` and `a->`, respectively. In the case of an output iterator, the types
>
> ```
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer
> ```
>
> may be defined as `void`.

In my case, `operator->` doesn't make sense since I'm just returning character types, so I can probably get away with `void` as @Richard Hodges suggested. I suppose the "correct" answer in the general case is to define some `pointer_proxy<T>` type (assuming such a thing doesn't already exist in the STL) that holds a `T` and defines an `operator->` that returns `T*` and use that for the iterator's `pointer` type